# How to write __str__ func in this case?

Tags: python, django

I have a 'user' model that have a OneToOneField to User Model and another model named 'user_agent' that have a foreign key to 'user' model. How can I use 'first_name' and 'last_name' in the `__str__` func?!

```
class users(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    user_type = models.ForeignKey(types, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    active_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    date_send_active_code = models.DateField(default=now, blank=True)
    count_send_active_code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    token = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

```
class user_agent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user_models.users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(agents, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return "(" + self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name + ")"
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `self.user.user.first_name` - but I kindly suggest you change your `user` model name to something like `Profile` to avoid confusion (and use CamelCase for your models names in general).

Comment: Thanks @quamrana for the fix 8-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self):
    return "({} {})".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

or if you're using python 3, use f strings:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"({self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name})"
```

EDIT: not sure if you're asking about the `user` or `user_agent` model, if it's the user model, then just use the code above but with `self.first_name` and `self.last_name` instead.

Also, typically python classes are upper case without underscores:
`class User(models.Model)` and `class UserAgent(models.Model)`

Comment: He is asking for dunder methods: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dunder-magic-methods-python/

Comment: Why don't you call `.format` in python 3? Now it looks like some kind of magic trick.

Comment: f-Strings are available from python 3.6, @CyberFly f-Strings perform better and look better